# Convert ordered dataFrame into a dictionary with the elements start for the bottom

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have data Frame with elements ordered by the Value column:

```
ID     Value
04      1
06      2
01      3
02      4
03      5
```

I need obtain the Dictionary with points as key and the list of points as values order in circle(first bottom, after top).

```
Dictionary: 
{
   01: [02,03,04,06],
   03: [04,06,01,02],
   ..
   ..
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one solution using `collections.deque`:

```
from collections import deque

dq = deque(df['ID'])
res = {}

for i in list(dq):
    res[i] = list(dq)[1:]
    dq.rotate(-1)
```

Result:

```
{'04': ['06', '01', '02', '03'],
 '06': ['01', '02', '03', '04'],
 '01': ['02', '03', '04', '06'],
 '02': ['03', '04', '06', '01'],
 '03': ['04', '06', '01', '02']}
```